# Comic that's like Spider-Man but violent, and the main character wears a mask with a heavy-metal aesthetic?

Tags: story-identification, comics, webcomics

So as the title says, I am looking for a comic wherein the protagonist has a coming of age origin arc similar to Stan Lee's Peter Parker.

The difference is that this dude has inherited or unlocked some old power related to the first man (Adam), and this allows him to see into and through peoples bodies like an X-ray. It grants him super strength and heightened reflexes.

The main character starts as a skinny teenager and then progresses into a hulk-like being towards the end of the series.

It's also quite a violent/gory comic (people get torn apart).

I read it last year on a website called readcomiconline

I am currently struggling to remember the title of it, so any help would be very appreciated.

If it helps at all, I think the title has a similar format to:

"The Strange case of {something something}"
or maybe:

"The Curious case of {something something}"

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  You tagged this with both "comic" and "webcomic;" which one was it?  Do you recall where and when you read it?

Comment: I read it on a website with a lot of free comics called readcomiconline.li

Comment: Did the character wear a costume? If so, how was the costume coloured? Also, did any well known superheroes or villains appear in the comic? Or were there any villains with distinctive powers or features that you can describe?

Comment: "this dude has inherited or unlocked some old power related to the first man (Adam), and this allows him to see into and through peoples bodies like an X-ray" — that was my favourite bit of the Bible.

Comment: Fair warning for anyone searching, the site in question send to be ridden with popups and ads.

Comment: @LogicDictates His "costume" was just him without a shirt on, and he wore jeans. I think he hand handwraps or bandages as well.
The villains had similar powers to him. They were part of a secret society. One of the more interesting villains was a buff guy wearing a waistcoat who had a handlebar moustache. He crucifies the main characters best friend quite early on in the story (sorry for spoiler)

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Hey I dunno man, it was a pretty wild story in general. I just remember that there was a biblical association to their powers.

Comment: @timi95 - Don't worry about spoilers when asking a story-ID question. It'll make it easier for us to find this for you if you tell us everything you remember. If you want, you can mark a paragraph of text as a spoiler (which means people will have to click on that section to read the text) by typing `>!` at the start of the paragraph.

Comment: The powers allowed them to regenerate completely from any kind of injury other than an injury to the brain.

[spoiler] >! I remember a scene with the moustachio'd villain of the first arc, where he punches through a steel door inside of a sea vessel (it could have been a submarine, or just a boat) just to get to his victim on the other side.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is likely [*The Strange Talent of Luther Strode*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Strange_Talent_of_Luther_Strode) by Justin Jordan.

Wikipedia says:

> "Luther Strode, a skinny teenager living alone with his mother, acquires enhanced physical abilities from a Charles Atlas analog: The Hercules Method. The creators intended the story as a slasher movie combined with the premise of Spider-Man-- Or in layman's terms: "What if Peter Parker didn't have the moral anchor of his Uncle Ben to guide him?"[2]"

[image]